# Does the Dusk Ball work in Dynamax Raids?

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield

Yesterday I failed twice in a dynamx raid battle to catch a pokemon.

- Flapple
- Coalossal

Both I attempted to catch with a Dusk Ball. I did not use a Repeat Ball on Flapple since I haven't owned one previously (*sad pokemon shield noises*)
Does the Dusk Ball work in Raids? It works best at night and in caves, so why not the long night? 
Which ball is best for uncatched pokemon in dyna raids?
Is a Quick Ball more favorable than a Timer Ball?
Is a Net Ball for water / bug types always the most efficient?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dusk balls work in raids, yes (since raids are technically caves), and happen to be the best option in general.

Do ensure you use Net Balls if it’s a bug/water type, and Repeat Balls if you've caught the pokemon before, as those give better bonuses than the Dusk Ball when applicable.

Source: [Various](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/259372-pokemon-sword/78219408) [user](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/259372-pokemon-sword/78172330) [forums](https://pokemondb.net/pokebase/330727/do-dusk-balls-have-their-affect-in-raid-battles).

---

As for the timer ball vs quick ball:

Timer balls are: `(1 + number of turns passed in battle * 1229/4096 (approx. 0.3))×, maximum 4× (13 turns)`

Quick balls are: `5× if used on the first turn of a battle; 1× otherwise`

Essentially, use quick balls on the first turn, then timer balls around 10 turns in.
Do note that because of how dynamax raids work, using a quick ball will always result in a 1x capture rate according to [this forum post](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/259372-pokemon-sword/78204275).

[Source](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9_Ball#Types_of_Pok.C3.A9_Balls)

Comment: Dynamax raids have unique catching mechanics. When a dynamax pokemon is available for capture, does that count as the "first turn" for the quick ball? Do turns fighting the dynamax mon count towards timer balls?

Comment: @Pyritie As far as I'm aware, no. They seem to be 1x according to [this forum post](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/259372-pokemon-sword/78204275).

Comment: @Corsaka it seems if you already have the pokemon registered in your PokeDex, a repeat ball is better than a Dusk ball. So it goes Net>Repeat>Dusk (when Net and Repeat bonuses are available of course)

Comment: @ValentinPearce Aye; although the question did specifically request previously uncaught pokemon in dynamax battles, I should probably include that for future viewers.